# Override easyadmin config file in Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, easyadmin

I'm working on a core **project A** that use `EasyAdminBundle`. This project is use as a dependency in another **project B**. I'm looking for a solution to override a part of **project A** EasyAdmin configuration in **project B**.

I tried to create same files with same path in **project B**:

- **Project B**: `/config/packages/admin/my-file.yaml`
- **Project A**: `/vendor/path/project-A/config/packages/admin/my-file.yaml`

but it still use project A configuration file.

The goal is to override configuration of an entity edit form.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt work"? Is the configuration of project A loaded but not overwritten or is only the configuration of project B being used?

Comment: @ferdynator Only project A configuration is used

Comment: Does your Project also `require` the `EasyAdminBundle`? IMHO the easiest solution would be to also require it, include project As configuration in your Project B and then overwrite as you wish

Answer (score 0):

look at the [overriding doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html), the path renaming is only possible for files that are in the `resource` folder.

For overriding a service (or in your case a configuration) you should use [service decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) and you won't need to rewrite the whole configuration but just the parameter that you need to change.